# GXT TabPanel with tabs on the top-left and top-right side

Tags: tabs, gxt, tabpanel

I am new in GXT and I'm trying to create TabPanel which has some tabs on the left side and some on the right (like on the picture 2). I can without any problem create the simplest TabPanel like on the picture 1.

[image]

In GWT I've managed to move some tabs to the right side in that way:

```
tabLayoutPanel.getTabWidget(i).getParent().addStyleName("right");
```

and CSS:

```
.right {
   float: right;
   margin-right: 6px;
}
```

But I don't find option like *getTabWidget* in GXT TabPanel.

Can you please help me with this case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do small hack to get access to tab handlers in GXT 3.

```java
class StylableTabPanel extends TabPanel {
    public void applyTabStyles(Widget widget, String styles) {
        findItem(getWidgetIndex(widget)).applyStyles(styles);
    }
}
```

Then:

```java
tabPanel = new StylableTabPanel();
HTML shortText = new HTML("Lorem ipsum...");
tabPanel.add(shortText, "Short Text");
HTML longText = new HTML("<b>lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</b>");
tabPanel.add(longText, "Long Text");
tabPanel.applyTabStyles(longText, "margin-left: 300px;");
```

Unfortunately, you have to compute left margin manually, because you cannot use "float: right" here: GXT developers decided to assign "width: 1000000px;" to UL element that holds tabs. So such floating rule simply pushes it beyond the right edge of your container (unless you have screen more than 1000000 pixels width ;]).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this but the tab headers still appeared on the top. Could you post the complete code?

Comment: You saved me after many hours of work with this!  Thank you.  Incidentally, how did you come up with the solution?  One thing I can't stand about GXT is that it isn't obvious to me how to modify the basic code base to do what I want.

Comment: @NickO: Just developer tools in browser (I prefer Chrome for development) and learning code source of GXT. If your IDE is tuned correctly (I'd recommend IDEA or Eclipse + Maven) then all needed sources will be on hand.

Comment: One more thing: from documentation about `applyStyles` method: _Style attribute names must be in lower camel case, e.g. "backgroundColor:white; color:red;_. Without it firefox doesn't display styles properly (in Chrome and IE it working fine).